# How to use numpy.random to generate random numbers from a certain distribution?

Tags: python, numpy, random

I am somewhat confused about how to use numpy.random to generate random values from a give distribution, say, binomial. I thought it would be

```
import numpy as np
np.random.binomial(10, 0.3, 5)
```

However, [NumPy reference page](https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/random/index.html) shows something like

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
rg = default_rng()
rg.binomial(10, 0.3, 5)
```

Both seem to be working well. Which one is the correct or better way? What is the difference if there is any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first block of code uses a `numpy.random.*` function. `numpy.random.*` functions (including `numpy.random.binomial`) make use of a global `RandomState` object which is shared across the application.

The second block of code creates a pseudorandom generator object with `default_rng()` and uses that object to generate pseudorandom numbers without relying on global state.

Note that `numpy.random.binomial` (in addition to other `numpy.random.*` functions) is now a legacy function as of NumPy 1.17; NumPy 1.17 introduces a [new pseudorandom number generation system](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/index.html), which is demonstrated in the second block of code in your question. It was the result of a [proposal to change the RNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst). The desire to avoid global state was one of the reasons for the change in this policy.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean the second block is going to replace the first block in the future?

Comment: Not exactly.  The changed RNG Policy doesn't say that `numpy.random.*` functions (including `numpy.random.binomial`) are obsolete.  Rather, in most cases, they should be avoided whenever reproducible "randomness" is desired, with unit tests being a possible exception.  See the [RNG Policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst#numpyrandom) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

```
import random
random.choice([2,44,55,66])
```

A crucial thing to understand about the random choice method
is that Python doesn't care about the fundamental nature of the objects that
are contained in that list.