# What is the difference between numpy.random's Generator class and np.random methods?

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-random

I have been using numpy's random functionality for a while, by calling methods such as `np.random.choice()` or `np.random.randint()` etc.
I just now found about the ability to create a `default_rng` object, or other [`Generator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.Generator) objects:

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
gen = default_rng()
random_number = gen.integers(10)
```

So far I would have always used

```
np.random.randint(10)
```

instead, and I am wondering what the difference between both ways is.

The only benefit I can think of would be keeping track of multiple seeds, or wanting to use specific PRNGs, but maybe there are also differences for a more generic use-case?

Comment: `randint` and other functions of `np.random` are now deprecated in favor of generators. The ability to use multiple independent streams of random numbers is one of their benefits, but generators also allow you to choose between different [bit generator algorithms](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/bit_generators/index.html), or even implement your own, so it is more flexible and may make reproducibility easier too.

Comment: The reproducibilty and flexibility arguments do make sense, although I guess writing your own bit generator is mostly limited to cryptographic application?

Comment: Yes, I'd say that is limited to very specific applications, research/study or particular cases where you are trying to match exactly the behavior of some other piece of software.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use numpy.random to generate random numbers from a certain distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59728162/how-to-use-numpy-random-to-generate-random-numbers-from-a-certain-distribution)

Comment: @PeterO. Not exactly, I do understand the usage, I was wondering if there were some underlying differences that I should be aware off. Or if there were any non-obvious benefits to switching to the new interface, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`numpy.random.*` functions (including `numpy.random.binomial`) make use of a global pseudorandom number generator (PRNG) object which is shared across the application. On the other hand, `default_rng()` is a self-contained Generator object that doesn't rely on global state.

If you don't care about reproducible "randomness" in your application, these two approaches are equivalent for the time being. Although [NumPy's new RNG policy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/nep-0019-rng-policy.rst) discourages the use of global state in general, it did not deprecate any `numpy.random.*` functions in version 1.17, although a future version of NumPy might.

Note also that because `numpy.random.*` functions rely on a global PRNG object that isn't thread-safe, these functions [can cause race conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59105921/why-is-numpy-random-seed-not-remaining-fixed-but-randomstate-is-when-run-in-para/59348689#59348689) if your application uses multiple threads. (`Generator` objects are not thread-safe, either, but there are ways to [generate pseudorandom numbers via multithreading](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/random/multithreading.html), without the need to share PRNG objects across threads.)