# What is the probability density function p(y) for y = np.random.normal(loc=np.random.randint(2),scale=1.2)?

Tags: python, numpy, random, probability-density

Suppose we generate a random variable as follows:

`y = np.random.normal(loc=np.random.randint(2),scale=1.2)`

Then what is the probability density function(pdf) of y i.e. p(y) in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose that, if `N(x, m, s)` is the PDF of a normal distribution with mean `m` and standard deviation `s`, the PDF for your distribution would be `(N(x, 0, 1.2) + N(x, 1, 1.2)) / 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *mixture* of an absolutely continuous distribution (the normal distribution) and a discrete distribution (the uniform distribution). In the case at hand, the distribution has a probability density function (PDF) of the following form:

∑<sub>*y*</sub> *f*<sub>*y*</sub>(*x*) * *g*(*y*),

Where—

- *f*<sub>*y*</sub> is the PDF for the normal(*y*, 1.2) distribution (mean of *y*, standard deviation of 1.2), and
- *g*(*y*) is the probability mass function for the discrete uniform distribution over the integers in [0, 2) (which can take on only the values 0 and 1 since `numpy.random.randint` excludes the endpoint).

See also page 16 of *Non-Uniform Random Variate Generation*.

In this case, the mixture PDF is:

- ∑<sub>*y* = 0, 1</sub> *N*(x; *y*, 1.2) * (1/2), or
- (*N*(x; 0, 1.2) + *N*(x; 1, 1.2)) / 2,

Where *N* is the PDF for the normal distribution.
See also a comment by "jdehesa".

(Note that `numpy.random.*` functions, including `randint` and `normal`, are legacy functions as of NumPy 1.17; see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599149/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-randoms-generator-class-and-np-random-meth).)