# the way of efficiently generating two random samples with dependency

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random, scipy

I would like to generate two set of variables, `h_min` and `h_max`,

```
h_max = [h_max_1, h_max_2, …h_max_2000]
h_min = [h_min_1, h_min_2,… h_min_2000]
```

Each element of `h_max` is generated based on uniform distribution, i.e.,

```
h_max = np.random.uniform(0,  20, 2000).
```

For each element, `h_min_i`, it should be generated based on the uniform distribution with range of 0, and corresponding `h_max_i`  In other words, `h_min_i = np.random.uniform(0, h_max_i)`
In stead of using iteration, how to efficiently generate `h_min`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `numpy.random.uniform` function allows the first and/or second parameters to be an array, not just a number. They work exactly as you were expecting:

```
h_max=np.random.uniform(0,20,2000)
h_min=np.random.uniform(0,h_max,2000)
```

However, `numpy.random.*` functions, such as `numpy.random.uniform`, have become legacy functions as of NumPy 1.17, and their algorithms are expected to remain as they are for backward compatibility reasons. That version didn't deprecate any `numpy.random.*` functions, however, so they are still available for the time being. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599149).

In newer applications you should make use of the new system introduced in version 1.17, including `numpy.random.Generator`, if you have that version or later. One advantage of the new system is that the application relies less on global state. `Generator` also has a `uniform` method that works in much the same way as the legacy function `numpy.random.uniform`. The following example uses `Generator` and works in your case:

```
gen=np.random.default_rng() # Creates a default Generator
h_max=gen.uniform(0,20,2000)
h_min=gen.uniform(0,h_max,2000)
```